# How does the 'High Caliber' award work?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I had a pretty good battle in my T95, hoping for the 'High Caliber' Battle Hero award, which is awarded for the highest damage dealt in a battle. When I checked the Team Score after the battle, I was greeted by this:

[image]

As you can see, the enemy KV-4 earned the High Caliber award despite having less damage dealt than me (T95). I also checked the detailed requirements, but found no explanation for this.

My only theory would be that I didn't get the award because I accidentally shot an ally, so the game didn't count me, even though friendly fire is off. Though I also had battles when I had the most damage dealt, shot an ally, didn't get the award, but no one else did (even though they met all the other requirements, like causing 20% of damage of the team).

So why did this KV-4 get the award, even though they clearly didn't have the highest damage dealt?

Answer (score 2):

Taken directly from the WoT Achievements guide:

https://worldoftanks.com/en/content/guide/general/achievements/

> High caliber:
>
> Awarded to players who dealt the biggest amount of damage during the battle. The damage dealt should be not less than 20% of enemy team tanks' HP sum, and not less than 1000 points. For receiving this award, **allies should not be hit with direct shots.** If two or more players have an equal amount of damage dealt, the achievement is granted to the player who has earned more XP for battle, including additional XP provided to Premium account users. If the amount of XP is equal as well, the achievement is not granted.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that I didn't get the award, but let me clarify the second part of my question: Why did the enemy IS-4 get the award? Even though I have shot an ally, that still does not mean they had the highest damage dealt.

Comment: I assume that the award then goes to the next person who is eligible, however I have not been able to find anything on that specifically.

Comment: Yeah it's weird, because in this battle that's true, but in other battles that i've played it isn't (and I play a lot of battles in a platoon where I aimlessly shoot my platoonmates just because I can)